# How to Change Vertical ViewPager Swipe Angle

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm using [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/prabhat1707/VerticalViewPager) for swiping vertically through images. The vertical view pager is strict when it comes to swiping angle, which means it will proceed with swiping only if it is a perfectly vertical swipe (no change in x coordinate).

But I have observed in the Inshorts app ([Inshorts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nis.app&referrer=utm_source=inshorts%20mobile)), they allow swiping up even if the swipe is not perfectly vertical. This makes the swiping smoother as users might not always be doing a 100% perfect swipe.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`ViewPager.PageTransformer`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer).

> A PageTransformer is invoked whenever a visible/attached page is
>   scrolled. This offers an opportunity for the application to apply a
>   custom transformation to the page views using animation properties.

```
 private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            }  else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                view.setAlpha(1);
                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [0,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);


                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                        + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
                view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use [**`VerticalViewPager`**](https://github.com/llRizvanll/InshortApp/blob/master/INSHORT/app/src/main/java/com/nightowl/inshort/VerticalViewPager.java)

Comment: This doesn't address the issue in the question. Instead after setting the transformer, ( viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new VerticalPageTransformer());)  I'm getting the previous fragment as a background of current fragment like this https://ibb.co/f1t3Lmc

Comment: Okay. Change Min Scale

Comment: I have used the VerticalViewPager you have provided at the end of your answer, with that it doesn't have the overlapping fragment issue. But still, it requires a perfect vertical swipe. No change from what I was having originally.!

Comment: Also, I don't think this behavior can be changed from the page transformer. If you carefully observe the call is made to transformPage method only if a perfect vertical swipe is made.